# Getting SQLDataSource Update Parameter from Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I am trying to get a parameter for my update from the gridview but it is an ID column that I do not want displayed. If I display the data in a boundfield it works fine but if I set the visibility to false the parameter is no longer sent to the update stored procedure. There does not appear to be a hiddenfield column that I can put into the gridview.

I have tried to set the parameters through the code behind but I am not certain on how to access the data I want the following code does not work (It sets the parameter to nothing

```
Protected Sub grvFacilityDisciplineBillingRate_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles grvFacilityDisciplineBillingRate.RowUpdating
    Dim row As GridViewRow = grvFacilityDisciplineBillingRate.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    sqlDisciplineBillingRate.UpdateParameters("Facility_ID").DefaultValue = CInt(row.DataItem("Facility_ID"))
    sqlDisciplineBillingRate.UpdateParameters("Discipline_ID").DefaultValue = CInt(row.DataItem("Discipline_ID"))
End Sub
```

And this is the front end with the two ID columns displayed, which is not what I want

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDisciplineBillingRate" runat="server" DataSourceMode="DataSet" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="SP_Facility_DisciplineBillingRates" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="SP_DiscplineBillingRate_Update" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Trustaff_ESig2 %>">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Facility_ID" DbType="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Facility_ID" DbType="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Discipline_ID" DbType="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="grvFacilityDisciplineBillingRate" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlDisciplineBillingRate" DataKeyNames="DisciplineBillingRate_ID"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="false" AutoGenerateEditButton="true"   CssClass="gridview">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            There were no discipline billing rates for this facility.
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Discipline" SortExpression="Name" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BillingRate" HeaderText="Billing Rate" SortExpression="BillingRate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Facility_ID" HeaderText="Facility_ID" SortExpression="Facility_ID" InsertVisible="false" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Discipline_ID" HeaderText="Discipline_ID" SortExpression="Discipline_ID" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply have to set the [DataKeyNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx) e.g. DataKeyNames="Facility_ID,Discipline_ID" and the SqlDataSource will figure it out for you when using GV's Update and Delete feature.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I could add more than value to that though looking at it now it is names and not name, haha.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Template fields and use a label control and hide them by setting visible="false".

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="College">
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lbl_Title" runat="server" text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' visible="false"></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

And use below code to access values from codebehind.

```
If gvrow.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
     Dim label1 As Label = DirectCast(gvrow.FindControl("lbl_Title"), Label)
'Access text of label using label1.text and cast to int or string
End If
```

You can eliminate using templated fields if you don't wish for ID columns.  And still access it using datakeynames property